# Why are no shadows showing up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have absolutely no shadows showing up in-game in Skyrim. I have my settings on Ultra High graphics and have checked all the advanced options. I have checked SkyrimPrefs.ini, and also tried deleting it and restarting Skyrim, with no improvement. I uninstalled all my mods and even reinstalled Skyrim fresh off Steam.

I'm running a Radeon HD 7950.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've checked your SkyrimPrefs.ini, but you don't mention what it says about shadows. Most likely there's a shadow setting wrong, and we can't eliminate that possibility without seeing those lines. Does deleting the ini and relaunching the game fix it? A fresh install won't remove it, so it's a prime suspect for lingering problems.

Comment: Updated my post to show that indeed I did that and it do not work.

Comment: I tried the mod fix and the ini fix in that post. Nothing.

Comment: Could you post the 3D Application settings (or a screenshot) at the AMD Vision Engine Control Center? That could help us troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with the driver for the 7900 series, and will be fixed eventually.

Comment: As of this post, I am running a [beta driver](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-3WINBetaDriver.aspx) for the 7900 series, and my shadows have returned!

Answer (score 2):

I am running an ATI HD 6670 and had the same problem. However, when in the game, I brought up the display options and fiddled with the Specularity Fade setting it from max to min and back to max and my shadows just started working.